# OracleCommand throws exception which is handed within package method

Tags: oracle, .net-core, oracle.manageddataaccess

I am having a strange issue where I am calling an Oracle package method call using Dapper's ExecuteAsync extension:

```
var rowsAffected = await Connection.ExecuteAsync(command, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Initially I posted this in Dapper GitHub project but after inspecting the code of the extension method, it is rather obvious that the exception is thrown by the OracleCommand and has nothing to do with Dapper itself, so I don't expect any feedback there, maybe some taunting which I hope it will not be materialised to a respective reply :-).
This Oracle package method internally has an exception handling mechanism which handles all exceptions and returns any errors in an out parameter called p_err_msg:

```
EXCEPTION

WHEN OTHERS THEN
v_err_msg := SQLERRM;
v_sql_code := SQLCODE;
v_err_msg := v_err_msg||' '||primaky_key||' '||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace;
p_err_msg := v_err_msg;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_err_msg);
END;
```

Calling the package method from any Oracle IDE (SQL Developer, TOAD etc) demonstrates the expected behaviour, not throwing an exception but returns the error message in the out variable.
Calling OracleConnection.ExecuteAsync for the same method with the same parameters results to the exception, which is handled in the package method, being thrown to the client.
Any idea why this happens and how it can be avoided. It is causing an issue because we want to make sure that exception is only thrown in any case that we fail to execute the method (connectivity issues) but not when an error internal to the package method is thrown.

Comment: what is the ORA error thrown back to your process ?

Comment: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "SCHEMA.PACKAGENAME", line 2014
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCHEMA"."TABLE"."COLUMN")
ORA-06512: at "SCHEMA.PACKAGENAME", line 1872
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: Please make sure that v_sql_code, v_err_msg and p_err_msg are declared big enough to store the resultstrings. If not, a character string buffer too small exception is raised within the exception block.

Comment: This is a good point. It crossed my mind but the fact that calling the package from SQL Developer or TOAD works fine, averted me from that path. I will have a go and let you know.